# Website Project and MVC together in IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a website project hosted in my IIS, added an MVC project as a Virtual Directory inside of it. When I try to browse my MVC virtual directory either using http://domianname/mvc or with http://domianname/mvc/LogIn (LogIn is the controller name) nothing happens, it is giving an error like
*The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server*.

I guess we can't host website project and MVC together.
In-order to host them together, we have to convert the website project to web forms project it seems.

In any sense the one which I am trying in para 1 can work?, just want to confirm, otherwise probably I have to move forward with the one I mentioned in Para 2.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're on the right track, but rather than have the MVC application as a Virtual Directory, it must instead be an Application Scope ("Convert to Application" in IIS).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. Wanted to confirm one more thing, will I be able to share the session when I add MVC as an application inside the existing website?

Comment: No, different applications don't share session state when used with the default InProc session state provider. If you use an alternative state server then you can, but they are not configured by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dai for your invaluable help.